# Missing Gmail notifications in windows 10 action center

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, email, gmail

Up until about two months ago I received Gmail notifications in the action center of Windows 10. Suddenly they disappeared.

The notification icon stays empty even when there is new mail. Google Chrome is enabled as my default mail service. Notifications are enabled. What is going wrong? Can it have something to do with POP mail and all this stuff? It is connected with Microsoft Outlook and I can see everything from Gmail there.

Comment: I'm confused I thought chrome didn't send anything through action center yet...it uses its own kind of notifications (as of today anyway...) https://www.chromestory.com/2017/09/chrome-action-center/

Answer (score 0):

All the notifications in Widows 10 are shown in action centre only (even for old win32 apps). If there is no notification there that means that chrome is not showing desktop notifications.

---

Make sure Google chrome is allowed to run in background.

1. Go to Google chrome settings page. Make sure you have checked the option to allow Google chrome apps to run in background even when Chrome is closed.
2. If you are using a laptop make sure battery saver is turned off.

---

If these things are set correct, Clear cookies from chrome and re-enable desktop notifications.

If you weren't asked to enable desktop notification by gmail, clear all data from chrome and try it again. The whole point is to turn that off and re enable the desktop notification. If this doesn't help you re-installing chrome may help but I am not sure. Also give the built in Mail app a try if other things fails.

Comment: How do I do this and what does it mean? All settings? Revert to original settings? What do I lose with this?

Comment: @SaraAgai Go to the History page and choose clear browsing data. You can choose what data to be deleted. But you must clear cookies for this to work. You will be logged out of all websites after clearing cookies. However your saved passwords and bookmarks will remain untouched unless you choose to clear them.

Comment: Did all that, but it didn't help

Comment: @SaraAgai After doing this logging into gmail where you asked to ***enable desktop notification*** by gmail? If you weren't asked clear all data from chrome and try it again. The whole point is to turn that off and re enable the desktop notification. If this doesn't help you then I am not sure what could. Re-installing chrome may help but I am not sure. Also give the built in Mail app a try if other things fails. i am sorry but that's all I know.

Comment: Same here as well but if I turn notifications off and then back on it works for a while and then stops. Also uninstalled and reinstalled chrome, no difference. I even ripped it out using Revo.

Answer (score 0):

Please turn off Mail Notification from Action center settings. After that make sure Chrome notifications are on. Restart the system once and check if all the settings remains the same ?

If all settings are same as you did then it should be ok and working.

Please also confirm if both Windows and MS Office are registered and licensed not pirated. There are some time issue with external notification if windows is not activated. same for MS office. (Outlook, etc) .

Hope this will fix the issue .